# What kind of graphics would you like better? [ pictures ]

Tags: android, game-design, graphics

I am looking forward to make an android game, something angrybirds style. I've already made my own engine and now have to decide what kind of graphics should I make.

It could be either realistic, like that

[image]

or a doodle-style like this

[image]

Right now the first one looks more appealing to me... on the other hand, doodle-graphics are very easy to draw and their transparency doesn't seem to slow down the engine much.

What do you think?

Comment: This is clearly an open-ended question.

Comment: No, don't replace your question with junk. It's still valuable to the community even if it is closed. If you really want it deleted, flag it for moderator attention. I don't know if you need to give a mod a good reason for it to be deleted, but if you really, really need it deleted, then safe to say you should say why and that might be a good enough reason to have it deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no depth perception in the doodle graphics approach which is why realistic version is likely to look more appealing. You can still use scribble-style graphics and still use some kind of visual "depth". Start by removing the "piece of paper"-background - there's room for more layers than one.